# Why is not working my jquery content slider?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a section with some news, and i want that when i click in my `<h3><a href="#">show more news(+)</h3>`, I want to show other list of articles, like a slider of the news that I have in this section.
Im beginner in jQuery and I was reading documentation and I found toggle function and I think that maybe serves my purpose.

Im trying this way above, but nothing is happening, can you please give me a help?

```
 <section id="posts-container">
               <div id="posts-body">
                   <div id="posts-content">
                   <h1>Posts</h1>
                   <hr class="line_break">


                   <article id="loop-posts">
                       <img src="image1.png" />
                       <a href="#">Title 1</a>
                       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p> 
                       <h3>Read more (+)</h3>
                   </article>


                   <article id="loop-posts">
                       <img src="image2.png" />
                       <a href="#">Title 2</a>
                       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem</p>
                       <h3>Read more (+)</h3>
                   </article>


                   <article id="loop-posts" class="toggle">
                       <img src="image2.png" />
                       <a href="#">Title 2</a>
                       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum</p>
                       <h3>Read more (+)</h3>
                   </article>

                      <article id="loop-posts" class="toggle">
                       <img src="image2.png" />
                       <a href="#">Title 2</a>
                       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem </p>
                       <h3>Read more (+)</h3>
                   </article>

                   </div>

                 <h3>
                    <a href="#">show more news (+)</a>
                 </h3>
              </section>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    $('#posts-container,#posts-container .toggle').slideToggle();
});;
```

CSS for this:

```
#posts-container .toggle{display:none;}
```

Comment: there is no .toggle or .teste in your code

Comment: I forgot did the complete translation from my post, sorry! I already update to .toggle! And its not working!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the click event handler to your hidden article containers - so the event will never fire. What you may want to do is to embed the hidden content within each article in a separate article container, and then your click event handler can do something like the following, to only toggle the details for this one article:

```
$(this).find ('.toggle').slideToggle();
```

I also noticed that your html is malformed - missing a closing div tag, and you have re-used ID values.

You can see a modified version at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HNvrK/1/

Comment: Thanks for your attention, the fiddle that you give is working there?

Comment: Yes. Clicking the title h3 expands the full details wthin the selected article.

Comment: Thank you for attention, but that isn´t what I want, maybe I´ve explained myself badly. What I want is, I have two news that appear in my html page, and I have two others that are in css with "display: none". I want that when I click "show more news," the two first news that appear in html change for the other two news that are marked with "class = "toggle". Hope I Was more clearer now!